# Orthogonality in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>2$, requires $x$ such that $x^2=-1$?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

In motivating the use complex numbers for quantum mechanics ([here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_do_you_need_imaginary_numbers_to_describe_Quantum_Mechanics2)), I found a claim that complex numbers are chosen because:

> Orthogonality in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>2$ requires $x$ such that
>   $x^2=-1$.

I'd like to understand, how this is seen?

Comment: let me say that Im very skeptic about that statement. May I ask you for a reference? where did you read it?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Here: http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_do_you_need_imaginary_numbers_to_describe_Quantum_Mechanics2

Comment: I share the skepsis, especially after having consulted the reference.

Comment: @mavavilj I remain skeptic. "Quantum theory needs existence of an $x$ such that $x^2=-1$." This is false: you dont really need complex numbers to formulate QM (though it would be rather cumbersome not to use them, so to speak). It is possible in principle to use just real numbers. "The reason for this is that orthogonal vector spaces, of dimension greater than 2, cannot exist otherwise" im not even sure what an orthogonal vector space is.

Comment: The real plane is a 2-dimensional Hilbert space ("orthogonal " space).No complex numbers are strictly needed. But not using them would be like stating all results of calculus  exclusively in the language of geometry and set-theory, or doing bookkeeping without negative numbers. Excruciating.